# Display an Alert Dialog when Futuredelayed time is finished in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an alertDialog which have duration of 8 second and I want to disaply another one when this time is finished automaticaly
this is my code:

```
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7), () {
Navigator.pop(context);
});
return AlertDialog(content: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: [
Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
Text('Attendi l\'invio del File')
],
),
);
```

at this stage when 8 second passed, I want to disaply another AlertDialog which confirm the uploading.
Any Input?

Comment: You want to show Alert box after 8 sec right?

Comment: exactly after 8 seconds should pop another dialog

Comment: You mean to say the first alert box is for 8 sec and after 8-second the first alert box will close and the second one is open right?

Comment: exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

```
  Timer _timer;
```

You have to call this show dialog on your button or where you want to call

```
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {
        _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();    // == First dialog closed
        });

        return AlertDialog( 
          title: Text('First Dialog'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Text('Content'),
          ),
        );
      }).then((val) {
    if (_timer.isActive) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
  }).then((value) {
    showDialog(
      // == Second dialog open
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              Text('Second Dialog')
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  });
```

Comment: no it doesnt work: 
Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter ( 6707): #6      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
E/flutter ( 6707): #7      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
E/flutter ( 6707): #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

Comment: Or let me know where you are calling this dialog?

Comment: In this way the first AlertDialog doesnt dissapear after 5 seconds.
I am calling this alert Dialog into a Widget:
Check the code https://codeshare.io/amnXMj
Look at line around 236

Comment: @EmanuelDeveloper actually tested the above code and after successfully run I added an answer